# PayPal Payments Advanced Posts back to some odd site

Tags: magento2.3.2, paypal-payments-advanced

I can say for sure, but after I installed Affirm as a payment method on my site, the other payment methods seem to be messed up.

Specifically in this case, payflow advanced, is only half working.  It actually does collect payment at PayPal, but when it is completed, it is posting back to some other site for some odd reason.  Because it doesn't post back correctly to my site, it tells the user it was canceled or incomplete, and the transaction doesn't show to have gone through in the backend.

PayPal tells me the payments are going, but it sees it posting to some other site and can't help me further.  It looks like the return URL is correct, and it shows the transaction approved: 
[image]

I noticed this on my payment screen if I use the iframe style payment with no cart or logo:
[image]

Or, if I use another style layout with the logo and subtotal:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your paypal manager at manager.paypal.com
Under Service Settings > Hosted Checkout Pages > Set Up
You should leave the **Enter Return URL**: blank and **Return URL Method** should be POST.

Comment: thanks for responding.  Yes, I checked it, and it was ok.

Comment: I added some more details in the original post